# Parsing Django QuerySet with JQuery using AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, parsing, django-queryset

I am returning a QuerySet of 1 and my JQuery looks like this

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#search_form").submit(function(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "object/search/",
            processData: false,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
                $.each(data, function(key, value){
                    alert( key + ': ' + value );
                    });
                }
            });
    });});
</script>
```

The alert will show up but all it returns 0: [object Object]. I would like to display the name property of the Object model that is being returned. Like using object.name. I am really stuck, your help in solving this problem is appreciated.

The code for my view is:

```
if request.is_ajax():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        format = 'json'
        mimetype = 'application/json'
        o = Object.objects.filter(name__icontains="bin")
        data = serializers.serialize(format, o)
        return HttpResponse(data, mimetype)
```

I am only returning 1 Object with this query but it is of type QuerySet.

EDIT. Here is what data looks like when returned.

```
>>> o
[<Object: Bin Ber>]
>>> data = serializers.serialize(format, o)
>>> data
'[{"pk": 1, "model": "objects.object", "fields": {"name": "Bin Ber", "roof": 3,                                               "depth": [3], "user": 1, "created_when": "2011-08-16 03:11:36", "shared": false,                                                          "projects": [1], "description": null}}]'
```

Comment: try having a look at `data` trough `console.log(data);`. There you should be able to see, what you have to access in the object stored in `value`. Probably value.name

Comment: without seeing the view where you are creating the data you are return its hard to kno whats going on here

Comment: I have updated my original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your edits:

```
$.each(data, function(key, value){
        alert( key + ': ' + value.fields.name );
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you link me a reference to making my own serializer? Also, the serializers.serialize line won't work unless it is a queryset.

Comment: I added what data looks like after being serialized as an edit to my original post.

Answer (score -1):

to see the data returned just use the javascript function JSON.stringfy(data);
that should show the data instead of [object object]